# Should I bag hard candy or not?

Tags: storage-method, candy

I just made a few candy canes...

[image: lots of candy canes]

If I'm going to transport them tomorrow, can I bag them up after they cool or should I keep them out as long as possible?  I'm worried about them getting sticky

Comment: Very nice! Impressive even!

Comment: I don't know much about candy making but if they're fully cooled, isn't bagging them in plastic exactly what candy manufacturers do?  If in doubt, you could always bag them in paper, which would breath better.

Comment: In doubt, you could roll them in confectioner's sugar before putting in the bag. Will be a bit detrimental to the appearance later, but prevents sticking really well.

Comment: Usually they get sticky because the sugars you've inverted by cooking the syrup will become very hygroscopic and absorb humidity from the air. If you're worried about stickiness, it's better to bag them in something airtight (and with a silica gel packet, if you have one)

Answer (score 1):

If you can shrink wrap them, do that.  They will likely get sticky if they are just bagged.  Manufactures bag them air-tight to keep the humidity out.  Per @sourd'oh pertinent note:

> "sugars you've inverted by cooking the syrup will become very hygroscopic and absorb humidity from the air"

Burying them in a bag of rice might protect them from humidity as well as preventing from looking as chalky as they would with confectioners sugar or corn starch. Speculating on the type of rice? I'd say Sushi rice would be least chalky.

p.s.  Chef Hats off- they look awesome!